# Guardar objeto en localStorage

Tags: javascript, api, local-storage

Estoy tratando de crear una lista de la compra que agrega los elementos mediante la voz. Hasta aquí todo funciona correcto.

El problema que tengo es que me está devolviendo el objeto vacío cuando intento guardarlo en localStore.

```js
        const speech = document.createElement('li');
        speech.innerHTML = transcript;

  
        // Añadir elemento grabado
        listaCompra.appendChild(speech); 

        // Guarda en localStorage

        localStorage.setItem('listaCompra', JSON.stringify(listaCompra)); // --> Lo almacena en localStorage, pero me devuelve un objeto vacio
    } 
    
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanto `listaCompra` como `speech` son objetos (con atributos y métodos) y así los pase por `JSON.stringify()` no los puede convertir en texto. Debe buscar otra solución...

Puede explorar el crear un array donde ingresa los elementos `transcript` y luego los recorre con un foreach para mostrarlos.

```
const unaListaParaAlmacenar = []
unaListaParaAlmacenar.push(transcript)
localStorage.setItem('listaCompra', JSON.stringify(unaListaParaAlmacenar))
```

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te ha dicho correctamente Omar, tienes que guardar en el *localstorage* los items en sí (en modo texto... ya sea la lista separada por comas o haciendo JSON stringify de una matriz con los items), no el cacho de DOM entero, ese no es "guardable".

Entonces guardas los items y luego los sacas y los pintas.

Es decir, guardar los datos, no la cosa entera.

Es como... yo te puedo decir que vayas a la tienda y compres los ingredientes para la pizza, que luego haces y metes en el horno, no te digo: "compra la pizza con el horno y con la cocina entera" y tráela.

Pues el horno y eso es el DOM ya pintado.

Y los ingredientes son los elementos.

Y tú estás cogiendo la listacompra (el div con los li) y queriendo guardar eso directamente.